# Alternative of JTATransaction

Tags: spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jta

I have an Spring based J2EE application which runs well on Weblogic, I wanted to move it to Tomcat.

It seems tomcat doesn't support JTA Transaction Manager without external jar help like  Atomikos, JOTM, Bitronix, SimpleJTA.

I am reluctant to make changes into my application where i am already using annotation based JTA transaction manager.

Are there alternatives for JTA Transaction Manager which I can use so that I am able to switch from weblogic to tomcat or tomcat to weblogic or any other server without changing my configuration file each time?

All in all what's best for transaction manager configuration when you want to keep your application (war) independent of server(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try TomEE. 
It's a Java EE 6 server that meets the Web Profile requirements and is based on Tomcat. 
So it will support JTA transactions. 
You can get it from http://tomitribe.com

Comment: Not the answer I was looking but would mark it as correct because it serves the purpose smewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a more direct link to TomEE: http://tomee.apache.org/download/tomee-1.7.2.html

Answer (score 0):

If your application is configured and developed to use Weblogic then chances are you are using JDNDI to lookup the JTA transaction manager and your datasources.

So any solution that supports the same lookups would work.

For Atomikos, we recently added (commercial) support for Tomcat's JNDI space - check out http://www.atomikos.com/Main/BuyOnline to learn more.

Hope this helps!